# How can we convert the sql in laravel eloquent / querybuilder

Tags: laravel, postgresql, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

Basically I need to show report where I need to provide few details based on cityId and postCode.

so if, cityId IS NULL  AND postCode IS NULL THEN count of those records should be under data1.

similarly,
 - WHEN    cityId IN (123, 456)   THEN count of those record should be in 'data2'
 - WHEN    cityId IN (789, 999) THEN 'data3'
 - WHEN    cityId IN (111, 222) THEN 'data4'
 - ELSE    'data5'

I have 2 queries here:

1. Convert this sql into laravel eloquent/querybuilder way.
2. The last condition which is mentioned

> COUNT(CASE WHEN cityId IS NOT NULL AND cityId NOT IN (123, 456, 789, 999, 111, 222) then 1 ELSE NULL END ) as \"data5\"
>   from customer
>           ")

has to be the else part of all above condition.

I have tried this but not able to achieve the desired result

```
$result = Customer::select(Customer::raw("SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN cityId IS NULL AND postCode IS NULL then 1 ELSE NULL END) as \"data1\",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN cityId IN (123, 456) then 1 ELSE NULL END) as \"data2\",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN cityId IN (789,999) then 1 ELSE NULL END) as \"data3\",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN cityId IN (111, 222) then 1 ELSE NULL END) as \"data4\",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN cityId IS NOT NULL AND cityId NOT IN (123, 456, 789, 999, 111, 222) then 1 ELSE NULL END ) as \"data5\"
from trial
        "))->get();
```

Desired Result: 
data1: 7
data2: 5
data3: 12
data4: 10
data5: 1

Comment: Your structure is a bit unclear to me, but chances are you'll want to use Laravel relationships and something like this:`Customer::whereHas('transaction', function($query) { $query->whereNotNull('tsid')->whereNotIn('afid', [123, 456, 789, 999, 111, 222]); }`

Comment: @ceejayoz I have updated my query for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

For time being, I got an alternative solution for my question mentioned above which somehow fix my 1st point question.

Still looking for 2nd point of question.

```
DB::table('customers')
        ->select(
            DB::raw('COUNT(CASE WHEN cityId IS NULL AND postCode IS NULL then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "data1",
                    COUNT(CASE WHEN cityId IN (123, 456) then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "data2",
                    COUNT(CASE WHEN cityId IN (789,999) then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "data3",
                    COUNT(CASE WHEN cityId IN (4965,4959) then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "data4",
                    COUNT(CASE WHEN cityId IS NOT NULL AND cityId NOT IN (123, 456, 789, 999, 111, 222) then 1 ELSE NULl END ) as "data5"')
        )->get();
```